# min-height: 100% not working if parent has only set min-height and not height

Tags: css

I have a parent container with a fixed `min-height` and a child container with `min-height: 100%`. The child container does not fill the full height of the parent container though.

It looks like this (Chrome 90):

[image: parent has min-height set; parent=green, child=yellow]

```css
.parent {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

But I would expect this:

[image]

Curiously when setting `height` instead of `min-height` on the parent, it works:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 200px;
}

.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know **why**?

Comment: Please read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) for more insight

Comment: Why? Because it creates an _unsolvable_ equation. To determine whether the parent element needs to be “min-height high” _or_ higher, we need to know the height of its _content_, the child element, first. And now you want to make the height of this child element in turn dependent on the parent height … notice the chicken/egg problem here?

Comment: the reference is always height. min-height OR height used with percentange need a **height** as reference on the parent (never min-height)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest workaround is to add `height: 1px;` to `.parent`. It doesn't not affect `min-height`, so you be good to go.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: 1px;
}

.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not a bug, it's by design

Comment: @TemaniAfif, yeah I've seen your answer, you are right! Thanks for new knowledge.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Horrible design, if I may say